# Angular2 setinterval blocked while dom changes

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, dom, setinterval

I have a basic Javascript/JQuery application that I'm now moving to Angular2, using material.angular.io for my UI.

In the old version, when I used "setInterval(func,200);" to query a server every 200ms, it was called every 200ms, even while adding DOM elements using JQuery's append(content) or html(content) functions.

Now in Angular2, while the DOM changes using *ngFor and the change is big (fetching ~200 rows from server and displaying them as table rows with Material components such as Toggle Buttons), everything freezes for about 1 second. The server's log shows me that indeed the calls were stopped for about 1 second before resuming every 200ms again.
But when I add the DOM elements in smaller groups (i.e: 10 items every 200ms) then everything's fine.

This also happens when I use F11 to toggle fullscreen, when the browser redraws the layout to match the new window size.

Using Chrome's debugging console, I can see that "Timer Fired(zone.js:2087)" is displayed with "Recurring handler took 731.18 ms" warning. I'm not sure if the problem is because of my code or because it's a material.io issue, but I think Angular's setInterval is different than the normal JavaScript setInterval?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let io of inputs; trackBy: trackByFn">
    <td>{{io.id}}</td>
    <td>{{io.name}}</td>
    <td>{{io.description}}</td>
    <td><mat-slide-toggle>Test</mat-slide-toggle></td>
    <td>{{io.device}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image: debug]

And the log from the server displaying the time from last query:

```
15:40:25.229 stat.service.ts:108 200
15:40:25.430 stat.service.ts:108 201
15:40:25.630 stat.service.ts:108 201
15:40:25.831 stat.service.ts:108 201
15:40:26.031 stat.service.ts:108 200
15:40:26.235 stat.service.ts:108 203
15:40:26.435 stat.service.ts:108 201
15:40:26.636 stat.service.ts:108 201
15:40:26.838 stat.service.ts:108 202
15:40:27.039 stat.service.ts:108 201
15:40:27.895 stat.service.ts:108 856 // WHEN THE COMPONENT LOADS
15:40:28.200 stat.service.ts:108 305
15:40:28.442 stat.service.ts:108 242
15:40:28.679 stat.service.ts:108 237
15:40:28.901 stat.service.ts:108 221
15:40:29.131 stat.service.ts:108 231
15:40:29.363 stat.service.ts:108 231
```

Comment: *it was called every 200ms* - that's unlikely. If main thread is blocked, it's blocked. The case isn't specific to Angular (it doesn't have its own setInterval, only the one that was patched by Zone.js) but to any blocking JS code. Try setInterval with big `for` loop and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the issue of ChangeDetection in Angular. When you are changing your object it re rendering the whole thing. Try to implement ChangeDetectionStrategy in your component and see there is any improvement. Your component code will look like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: "your-comp",
  templateUrl: "./your.component.html",
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class YourComponent{
  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

 // this.cdr.markForCheck(); use code for change on DOM when you get data in observable
}
```

Hope it will help

Comment: No. As I said, this also happens when I click F11 to toggle full screen, and only when the DOM is being modified. When the DOM is set, and only the data changes, the binding works as it should with no problems. Just the initial DOM modification takes time.

Comment: 200 rows is not much  data I rendered around 10000 rows having 7 property and never seen any issue. You should dig in it to solve this issue. May be this will headache in future.